# Problema com flip card

Tags: javascript, html, css

A animação de flip card funciona na primeira div, porém não funciona na segunda div

código
https://codepen.io/Jarles7/pen/yLjwEQq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boa tarde beleza?

Este código está um pouco bagunçado e com uns erros de sintaxe, mas isso você irá se aperfeiçoar com o tempo, apenas tome cuidado. Neste caso aconselho atribuir duas functions, uma para a primeira div e outra para a segunda div. Logo, atribua também classes especificas para cada div. Como exemplo:

HTML Code:

```
    <div class="skillbox flip div1">

    <div class="skillbox flip div2" >
```

JS code:

```
 const skillbox = document.querySelector(".div1");
        skillbox.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
          skillbox.classList.toggle("flip")
        }) 

  const teste = document.querySelector(".div2");
        teste.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
          teste.classList.toggle("flip")
        })
```

Crie funções para cada div.
Duas dicas extras, sempre que quiser adicionar mais de uma class a mesma div, você pode apenas dar um espaço e adicionar assim mesmo. E aconselho a nunca utilizar ID e mais de um mesmo elemento. Utilize nesses casos class, use ID para elementos únicos do cod.

Boa sorte man